# Can we use both jQuery and AngularJS in our web application?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-web-api

Can we use both jQuery and AngularJS in our web application? I have read some advice saying not to use both together in your project, because each has a different lifecycle.

Our requirement is to build a responsive web application using ASP.NET WebApi and AngularJS; now to make our application responsive we wish to use Bootstrap, and Bootstrap requires both Bootstrap CSS and the jQuery library; so should we add both the jQuery libary and the AngularJS library to our project?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can but it's not recommended because jQuery adds alot overhead.
If you would code the "angular way", then you won't break the angular functionality. Like example if you try to adjust a value of a field, then your scope wouldn't update until you manually trigger a digest. It leads into rubbish code and inconsistent behavior.

> **Does Angular use the jQuery library?**
>
> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the
>   application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your
>   script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the
>   subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.
>
> Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7
>   and newer might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that.

[Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#does-angular-use-the-jquery-librar)

Also see this question: [Should we use jQuery with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007792/should-we-use-jquery-with-angularjs)

If you are really really sure that you want to use jQuery, make sure that you include the jQuery script first. Angular will load jQuery in place of JQ lite then.

Comment: That link for "Should we use JQuery with AngularJS" is pretty useless since they are talking about migrating a website from JQuery to AngularJS, not whether JQuery *works* with Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can use both Jquery and AngularJS in the same project. According to the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)

**Does Angular use the jQuery library?**

> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the
>   application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your
>   script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the
>   subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.
>
> Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer
>   might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that.

You also need to remember that,

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery.

If you want to use any Jquery plugin in the project, make sure you convert them into angular directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery together with AngularJS. AngularJS also have a lightweight version [JQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) which contains all the JQuery functionality the AngularJS project needs.

In first instance it would be recommended to use pure AngularJS, but if for whatever reason just AngularJS doesn't cut it, you can use JQuery to fill in the void. If you do choose to use JQuery alongside AngularJS you'll have to start taking into account that everything you do outside of the view of AngularJS will require extra thought on your part, because if angular doesn't know about a change it won't apply that change to anything.