# Why I get error Module Error in my Angular project?

Tags: angularjs

I use Angularjs 1.2.21 in my project.

I download and install angular-route.min.js file

from this [resource](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/).

I get this [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=dashboard&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.21%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.router%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.21%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dui.router%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FMobile%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A450%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FMobile%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A391%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FMobile%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A21%253A388%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FMobile%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A208%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FMobile%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A290)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520e%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FMobile%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A148)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FMobile%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A225%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FMobile%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A290)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520e%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FMobile%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A148)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520gc%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FMobile%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A36%253A252)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMobile%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:6:450%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMobile%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:34:28%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMobile%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:7:290)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMobile%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:33:148)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMobile%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:33:225%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMobile%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:7:290)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMobile%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:33:148)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20gc%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMobile%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:36:252)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMobile%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:18:60)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fc%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMobile%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:18:277).

Here is main module definition:

```
angular.module('dashboard', ['ngRoute','layers'])
.config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {});
```

Any idea why I get the error above?

Comment: did you referred `'layers' ?

Comment: @Michael Do update your Angularjs file version to 1.3. That's it.

Comment: In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.x or later, be sure that you've installed ngRoute.

Comment: @RameshRajendran what do you mean by referred 'layers'?

Comment: did you referred 'layers' script file in your main.html page?

Comment: @Ravindra I have installed angular-route.min.js

Comment: @RameshRajendran, yes ofcourse

Comment: @geminiousgoel I can't install angularjs 1.3 because I have jquery version 1.8.4

Comment: have you load `angular-route.min.js ` file in `index.htm` page?

Comment: @ShaishabRoy, Yes I have loaded  angular-route.min.js after angularjs.js

Comment: @RameshRajendran, any idea can I use any other module instead ngRoute ?

Comment: according to your error message don't find `ngRoute` module . to ensure check your page source is `angular-route.min.js` file is loaded or not ... if loaded it should work

Comment: @ShaishabRoy I changed location of the angular-route.min.js file is loading. Now it's ahow another error:(

Comment: what is the new error are you getting ?

Comment: @Michael do not use Jquery with Angular. If you do, list of errors will be there soon. Search this over internet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699238/can-we-use-both-jquery-and-angular-in-our-web-application