# I can't use JQuery : Cannot find name '$'

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem using jQuery in my project (with Angular and boosted which is a fork of bootstrap). The error is below:

> ERROR in folder/containing/my/component.ts: error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery`.

I have installed `@types/jquery` and `jquery`, and I have added the script in angular.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
   // ...
  "boosted": "^4.3.1",
  "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
},
"devDependencies": {
  // ...
  "typescript": "~3.1.6"
}

"scripts":[
  // ...
  "node_modules/@types/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.d.ts",
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
]
```

Comment: npm install --save-dev @types/jquery

Comment: As an aside to your question, if you're using Angular then you shouldn't be using jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53534894/519413

Answer (score 4):

Try to install jquery.

```
npm install jquery
```

And then import jquery as $. like below

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: did $ have a modal method ? I'd like to show a modal: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript