# Model is not updating after select a date

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker, mobile-angular-ui

The following code work with pure angularjs correct, but when I integrate it to a Mobile Angular UI App it does not update the model after selecting a date. If I edit the input field without the date picker it works fine.

Template:

```
<div>
<label>{{myLabel}}:</label>
<input class="form-control datetime-picker" placeholder="{{myPlaceholder}}" ng-model="ngModel" required="required">
</div>
```

Directive js code:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('MeetingApp.directives.HelpDirective', []);

    app.directive("datetimePicker", function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: "datetime-picker.html",
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                myPlaceholder: '@',
                myLabel: '@'
            },
            require: ['?^ngModel'],
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                $(element).find('.datetime-picker').datetimepicker({
                    format: "dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii",
                    autoclose: true,
                    language: "de",
                    startDate: new Date(),
                    minuteStep: 10
                });
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

Usage:

```
<form method="post" id="meetingForm" ng-controller="MeetingController as meetingCtrl" novalidate>    
    <datetime-picker my-placeholder="Startzeit" my-label="Startzeit" ng-model="meetingCtrl.meeting.start"></datetime-picker>
    <datetime-picker my-placeholder="Endzeit" my-label="Endzeit" ng-model="meetingCtrl.meeting.end"></datetime-picker>
</form>
```

Github link: https://github.com/knobli/meetingApp

To run the app:
    npm install -g bower yo gulp generator-mobileangularui
    bower install
    gulp build
    gulp

Comment: @pankajparkar the element is a div element containing the label and input element.

Comment: do try `$(element).find('.datetime-picker').datetimepicker` looks like everytime you are initializing datepicker for all the element which has `datetime-picker` class

Comment: @pankajparkar thanks that works, but it does not solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `require: ['?^ngModel'],` looks strange to me...
If you require a thing, in my opinion, it can't be optional, right?

Try using `require: 'ngModel',` and let me know if it works.

You need to use this:

```
dpElement.on('changeDate', function(ev) {
            //need to run digest cycle for applying bindings
            scope.$apply(function() {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ev.date);
            });
        });
```

But be aware to not call your parameter `event`. This is a reserved word in JavaScript. [Take a look at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

Comment: Thanks, the three changes (require, event name, parameter name) did the job.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are using any jQuery plugin you need to update your `scope` bindings manually, because any changes from outside angular context would not run angular digest cycle.

For updating `ng-model` on change of input you need to update an ng-model on its change event `dp.change`.

**Directive**

```
app.directive("datetimePicker", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "datetime-picker.html",
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            myPlaceholder: '@',
            myLabel: '@'
        },
        require: ['?^ngModel'],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var dpElement = $(element).find('.datetime-picker');
            dpElement.datetimepicker({
                format: "dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii",
                autoclose: true,
                language: "de",
                startDate: new Date(),
                minuteStep: 10
            });
            dpElement.on('dp.change', function(event) {
                //need to run digest cycle for applying bindings
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(event.date);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Similar [**SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29194068/2435473) Here with detailed explanation.

Comment: It does not work, but I read already other posts about this jquery update behaviour. I provide a github link with all the dependencies.

Comment: @knobli does your code has problem only with mobile? or chrome is also showing same issue?

Comment: @knobli could you please create a plunkr/fiddle

Comment: There are a lot of dependencies, as I said with native angularjs it works. Couldn't you work with the github link? There you have the bower file with all the dependencies.

Comment: @knobli do you required more help on this?