# Jquery Time Picker inside ng-repeat is not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, datetimepicker

As i am proceeding into my project. In Some place i need to repeat few input fields which contains two time html5 field. Everything was going well when i was testing in Chrome but when i tested in in firefox it is showing as text field. (Firefox does not support time and date html5 fields). So i started finding some plugin but nothing worked as my requirements.

> So I have already wasted lot of time so I am explaining my requirements very clearly.

HTML CODE.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="timingindex in timingsArray">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="timings[$index].group">
        <option value="Pre-Priary">Pre-Priary</option>
        <option  value="Primary">Primary</option>
        <option  value="Middle">Middle</option>
        <option  value="Senior">Senior</option>
      </select> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="timings[$index].season">
        <option value="summer">Summer</option>
        <option value="winter">winter</option>
      </select> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      Starts: <input type="time" ng-model="timings[$index].starttime"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">   

      Finish : <input type="time" ng-model="timings[$index].endtime">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <button ng-click="addNewTimings(timings[$index])">Save and Add More</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <button ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeTimigns($index)">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now I want to use this [jquery UI Plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) this is ok for me because i am using default date picker of jquery UI in place of my html5 default time field.

> How i am trying to workaround using this plugin with my angular project is. ?

- I have to add this jquery for each picker i need.

  $('#slider_example_1').timepicker({
      timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT'
  });
- I am thinking to give unique name like id="slider_starttine_{{$index}}"  and similarly for endtime (Check my html code for clarity what i am saying for angular)
- Whenever new item is added i will add two line jquery using $index.

  > But problem is that this strategy is not working.

Any help will be welcomed. Thanks in advance. Please comment below if you need more clarification. I am not sure what exactly i should write here.

Comment: Include jQuery and jQuery UI as dependency and create a custom [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) (do DOM manip the angular way also I would suggest looking into [angular ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/) which has a lot of the jquery UI stuff done the angular way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are running jQuery code to `timepicker` on element before the element contents gets rendered on html

Better you should wrap your jQuery plugin code in directive and write bind `timepicker` to that element inside directive link function. Binding jQuery plugin from the directive is considered as best practice.

**Markup**

```
<input type="time" timepicker ng-model="timings[$index].starttime">
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('timepicker', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            //binding timepicker from here would be ensure that
            //element would be available only here.
            element.timepicker(); //your code would be here.
        }
    }
});
```

Like the way did in [**this SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29194068/2435473)

Comment: but the timepicker i am using need unique id. How i use that code. I have no time check whole library now will that element take care of every thing ?