# Angular JS Custom Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am making a custom directive for `datetimepicker` in Angular. But the `$scope.start_date` does not contain the value that is displayed in the input datetimepicker. I have tried using `$apply`.

```
campaign.directive('datetimepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datetimepicker({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: try changing element to scope i.e.  scope.datetimepicker

Comment: it would be useful to see the rest of the code. Ideally in a plunker.

Comment: What's the html code?

Comment: my html code is <div class="col-md-8"> <input required class="form-control" datetimepicker ng-model="form.start_date" /></div>

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/29194068/2435473