# angular (jquery timepicker) is unable to detect changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, timepicker, angularjs-ng-show

Im new to angular and while doing a small exercise, i was struck and
I wanted to enable the ng-show depending upon previous row timings and time input is through jquery timepicker, but my angular is unable to read the value of timepicker to show next row

My code is shown below

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Time From</th>
      <th>Time To</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="row1" size=6/ disabled>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="timepicker1" ng-model="dup_row1 " size=6/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="show_row2()">
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="dup_row1" size=6/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="dup_row2" size=6/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and my script code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.row1 = "00:00"
  $scope.show_row2 = function() {
    if (($scope.dup_row1 && $scope.dup_row1.substring(0, 2) < 24)) {
      return true
    }
  }
$('#timepicker1').timepicki();
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

[my plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/bxV714iPtiO4QQtIlc24?p=preview)

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29194068/2435473 , will give you more idea about how will it work

Comment: Do you need to bind your controller `ctrl`, isn't it?

Comment: ya i believe angular is loaded first and on top it timepicker is loaded, hence the value of input is empty......correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 1):

Load jQuery before an AngularJS to avoid compiling DOM again with an jQuery `$`

You should play with the DOM using `directive` if you are using any jQuery plugin. You could create you own directive that will do create the `timepicki` for your element.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('timepicki', [

  function() {
    var link;
    link = function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
      element.timepicki();
    };

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: link,
      require: 'ngModel'
    };
  }
])
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/6OKXMq890Ou3yOhsShDs?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for ur reply...i appreaciate your help....but when i have added a submit button also and found my timepicker is still giving a null value...can you please help me with that...my plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/T43aPZJsUP8I4saLRnA9?p=preview

Comment: @amogh you need to add onchange event on element inside your directive that will set the `ng-model` value