# How to call the datepicker using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I want to call datepicker using angularjs.  I have tried with some piece of code, can someone help me on what is missing. In html tag getting "unknown attribute datepicker". Appreciate you help.Thanks.

```
<input ng-model="datePicker" id="txt_parentcrid" type="text" placeholder=":input" datepicker/>
   var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.directive("datepicker", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: "ngModel",
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                var updateModel = function (dateText) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
                    });
                };
                var options = {
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                    onSelect: function (dateText) {
                        updateModel(dateText);
                    }
                };
                elem.datepicker(options);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: it should work..if you have included `datepicker` & `jQuery` correctly..

Comment: @pankaj Parkar i have added  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> anything needs to add except this?

Comment: would recommend to readup on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29194068/2435473

Answer (score 0):

Like Pankaj mentioned in the comments, sounds like you are missing some file. Make sure you are including everything in the right order. Simple things like adding `jQuery` before `jQuery UI` might be your answer.

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/r6vuxkq5/)