# Jquery Timepicker doesn't update model in AngularJS directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When I press any keyboard key, e.g. 0, and if I lose focus, it automatically gets set to control as 00:00, but it does not update the model value.

```
angular.module('test').directive('timePicker', [function () {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',
  scope: {
    model: '=ngModel'
  },
  link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

    element.timepicker({'timeFormat' : 'H:i'});

    ////element.on('change', function () {
    ////  scope.$apply(function () {
    ////    scope.model = element.datepicker('getTime');
    ////  });
    ////});


    ////$scope.$watch('model', function (newValues, oldValues, scope) {
    ////  console.log("Nothing here");
    ////});       
  }
}
}]);



<input id="startTime" type="text" name="startTime" data-ng-model="vm.data.StartTime" time-picker  />
```

I am not able to validate time because of model is not updated.
commented code is what I have tried to update value.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: have you defined the module properly, as i can see you have used a getter of module syntax.

Comment: Yes, It is working when I select a value from dropdown , only issue is when it automatically set value at that time model value is not updated.

Comment: I think you had it right, with the binding of the element on change, although you should be using "$scope.$apply()" (with a $ at front as you are passing it like that in the function) instead of "scope.$apply()". Have a look at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker as well :)

Comment: I am unable to access $scope or scope inside change event.

Comment: You could find better explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29194068/2435473

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because the timepicker changing the value of the input field (probably using `$("input").val("newval")`) does not trigger any event that angular is listening on in order to start a digest cycle.

Sponateously, I can find an [angular-jquery-timepicker](https://github.com/Recras/angular-jquery-timepicker) that you might want to use. Looking at its source code, it seems like it is listening for a `changeTime` event:

```
element.on('changeTime', function () {
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.model = element.val();
  });
});
```

The `changeTime` event is also [documented](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) (see “Event Example”).

Try it out in this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UHdkgSRX0fv2sUB15FoM?p=preview). It turns out that listening for the `change` event also works.

Comment: I already know this library, but I need to know what is wrong in my code that change event is fired but linker parameter are not accessible in it.

Comment: What do you mean, they are not accessible in it? What error message are you receiving?

Comment: Also, it should be `$scope` instead of `scope`, I just saw that that’s how your parameter is called.

Comment: In that case I don't know what you mean by “parameters are not accessible”. From the JavaScript perspective, I think it’s not possible that you cannot access `$scope` if you run the code inside the link function.

Comment: you are right, it must be accessed but for some reason it was not, BTW I am able to run the code without any undefined object exception

Comment: Thanks for spending your precious time