# Fullcalendar.js calendar disappears in Angular

Tags: django, angular, controller, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar.js in one of my web applications. It appears on the app's landing page when the page first loads a base template with an angular script. I initiate the calendar in a document.ready function. If I navigate to a different angular controller, and than navigate back to the home page without a page reload the calendar does not show up.

Relevant HTML

```
<head>

    <title>Ample Admin Template - The Ultimate Multipurpose admin template</title>

    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">


    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="/static/js/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/static/js/mobile_angular/mobile-angular-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/static/js/mobile_angular/mobile-angular-ui.gestures.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Luegg/angularjs-scroll-glue/master/src/scrollglue.js"></script>
    <script src='/static/angular-upload/angular-upload.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/static/js/ui-bootstrap.js'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src="/static/js/dealer_bundle.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            setTimeout(function () {
                var calendar = $('#calendar');
                calendar.fullCalendar({
                    dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                        $('#my-event').show(400);
                        $('.calendar-overlay').show(500);
                        $('#event-date-title').html('Add Event for ' + date.format());
                        window.holiday = date.format();
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);

        });

        function closeHolidayWindow() {
            $('#my-event').hide(400);
            $('.calendar-overlay').hide(500);
        }
    </script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/css/colors/blue-dark.css" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/css/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/css/sidebar-nav.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/css/dealer_base.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/fullcalendar.css">
</head>

<!-- Calendar Popup -->
        <div class="calendar-overlay"
             style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 2000; background: black; opacity: .7; display: none;">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 m-b-30" style="min-height: 370px;">
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="my-event" class="modal fade none-border in" style="display: none; z-index: 3000;">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"
                                onclick="closeHolidayWindow()">x
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">
                            <strong id="event-date-title">Add Event</strong>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Event Name</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Insert Event Name" name="title"
                                               type="text"
                                               ng-model="holiday.name">
                                        <input type="hidden" id="holiday-date" name="event-date" value=""
                                               ng-model="holiday.date">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Start Time</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Start Time" name="start-time"
                                               type="time"
                                               ng-model="holiday.start_time">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">End Time</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="End Time" name="end-time" type="time"
                                               ng-model="holiday.end_time">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-white waves-effect" onclick="closeHolidayWindow()">Close</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-success save-event waves-effect waves-light" type="button"
                                ng-click="saveHoliday()">
                            Create Event
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Calendar Popup -->
```

App.js

```
/* eslint no-alert: 0 */

'use strict';

var app = angular.module('SocialAutoDealerPortalApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'mobile-angular-ui',
    'mobile-angular-ui.gestures',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'SocialAutoDealerPortalApp.controllers'
]);

app.run(function ($http, $transform, $rootScope, $window, $location, $route, SharedState) {
    console.log('App Running');
});

var portal_controllers = angular.module('SocialAutoDealerPortalApp.controllers', []);

// this allows our ajax requests to work with django by providing the security token
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/portal_home.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'portalHome'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/sign-in', {
        templateUrl: 'views/sign-in.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'dealer_signin'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/recover-pw', {
        templateUrl: 'views/forgot_password.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'passwordRecover'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/reset_password/:user/:reset_code', {
        templateUrl: 'views/reset_password.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'passwordReset'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/info', {
        templateUrl: 'views/info-hours.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'infoHours'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/inventory', {
        templateUrl: 'views/inventory.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'inventory'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/vehicle/:vid', {
        templateUrl: 'views/vehicle_userlist.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'vehicleSelections'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/user/:uid', {
        templateUrl: 'views/user_activitylist.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'portalProfile'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/employee/:uid', {
        templateUrl: 'views/employee_profile.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'portalEmployee'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/manage-employees', {
        templateUrl: 'views/manage_users.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'manageUsers'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/leads/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/threads.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'portalThreads'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/messages/:mid', {
        templateUrl: 'views/message.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'portalChat'
    });
});
```

Comment: You should consider creating wrapper directive to bind your calendar to element, You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28808502/2435473)

Comment: Are you sure it is not caused by stick? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/

Comment: Have you tried calling [render](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/render/) when the calendar view (landing page) is selected?